# OpenStack Swift is there a module to redirect client by region location?

Tags: cdn, region, openstack, openstack-swift

I am currently playing with OpenStack Swift, my expectation is to deploy a multi region cluster. For example one node of the swift cluster will be deployed in the US and one in EU.

Is there a module or an option in swift-proxy to redirect client by region location?

If it is not possible, what other solutions do you suggest? Should I develop my own proxy server that redirects client to the nearest node (with geoloc/maxmind etc.)?

Resources:

- [Configuring a multi-region cluster](http://www.mirantis.com/blog/configuring-multi-region-cluster-openstack-swift/)
- [Proxy server configuration](http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-object-storage/admin/content/proxy-server-configuration.html)

**EDIT**: One of the contributor to Openstack answered me the code for geographically-distributed Swift clusters does not yet exist in the Git repository. The link I have posted in the resources is a bunch of proposed changes. There is no  code in Swift to do
that sort of redirection. I will need to write a piece of WSGI
middleware and stick it in the proxy server's middleware pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your needs, but as you know openstack has a side project [keystone](https://github.com/openstack/keystone), in which endpoints are stored with Region information. If you want to write your own implementation that can be a starting point. Also since their a cdn tag in your quest there is a project named [sos](https://github.com/dpgoetz/sos), making openstack swift work as a cdn server. Hope these can help you  on your implementation.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I also found this project [Colony](https://github.com/nii-cloud/colony) and the Colony-Dispatcher seems to be what I am looking for!